# Memory issues with iOS keyboard extension

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, ios-keyboard-extension

I am developing a custom keyboard extension. The extension displays a set of images in a UICollectionView and has the option to copy and paste the image in the host application. 
When I copy and paste the image, the keyboard disappears but what is strange is when the keyboard appears again, there is an increase in consumed memory. Does the keyboard not get unloaded when it disappears?

I have profiled it and there seems to be no memory leak. Has someone else observed this?

Comment: Keyboard views are supposed to be unloaded, but I've seen them stick around for longer under the debugger. Do you use `[UIImage imageNamed:]` to load your images?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293187/