# Custom keyboard is not showing up in Real IOS Device

Tags: ios, iphone, custom-keyboard

I have created custom keyboard extension. Its working fine on Simulator. When I run custom keyboard extension in Simulator it works fine and able to change between keyboards.

When I try to run same in Real IOS device. it doesn't work . When I click on Globe icon on keyboard. It freezes for a second and show same keyboard again.

Debugger showing this : **Program ended with exit code: 0**

Unable to test custom keyboard in my real device.

Any help here ?

Comment: Your keyboard is crashing. You need to debug why that is happening.

Comment: Its working fine on Simulator. Its showing up the keyboard in simulator

Comment: Did you enable all privileges of the keyboard in thr settings?

Comment: Yes, enabled. I have provided full access in the settings after adding keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through many posts in stack over flow. I found the solution. Program ended with exit code 0 means no error at all.
Its an memory issue. I'm using images and they are near about 111 MB in size. So its crashing due to memory issue.

here is the reference i found : [Custom KeyBoard get terminated due to memory pressure in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293187/custom-keyboard-get-terminated-due-to-memory-pressure-in-ios-8)

After removing images and just droping 5 images in the build folder. It works and keyboard start working. Simulator takes system memory that's why its not crashing there.